# Sencha Touch DataView and highlighting a row when selected

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a dataview list inside a container which is displaying items correctly inside the view. However, whenever I click on an item it isn't getting highlighted.

I've added this to the view containing the DataView list:

```
  onItemTap: function (container, target, index, e) {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);  // WARNING: without this call, the row will not become selected
    }
```

I've read that the item won't get selected if I don't have the above. I can see this event being fired ok too.  If I debug through the Sencha Touch source code, I can see the CSS class x-item-selected is being added to the DIV wrapping the list item, but there is no highlighting of the row.  This works fine on normal lists so what am I missing?

**Updated CSS which seems to work.**

```
.x-dataview .x-data-item.x-item-selected
{
    border-top-color: #006bb6;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0398ff, #007ad0 3%, #005c9d);
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Sencha Touch Dataview doesn't provide any highlighting. Add a background or something to `.x-item-pressed` or `.x-item-selected` class and you will get the desired effect.

Comment: On a normal list view, this class get's added to the selected item and it shows as highlighted. It looks like the CSS has this defined correctly for lists but not the structure of the DOM for a selected item within a dataview. I'm not a CSS expert, how would I fix this?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm going to do. I got is selecting by using the above code that I've added. Not sure how SASS friendly this is. I suspect not.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the **selectedCls** in the config block?

see the following link for detailed information

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-selectedCls